# Schema Design for a questionnaire with single or multiple choices with no right / wrong answer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, schema

Firstly, I went through tens of questions over here related to mine, but couldn't quite find what I'm looking for, hence asking a seemingly duplicate question again.

I have a requirement for a questionnaire of about 30 fixed questions for all users which can have,

- Single select options (Text or Text with images)
- Multi select options (Text or Text with images)
- Free text
- Date fields

There is no right or wrong answer since the questions cater to a user's preferences. I've been working on a postgres schema design, which looks something like this.

--Questions Table--

```
   id int
   question varchar
   description varchar
   type varchar -> single select/multi select or free text with no options
   createdAt timestamp
   updatedAt timestamp
```

--Options--

```
  questionId int -> foreign key to questions.id
  type varchar -> text or text with image
  text varchar
  image varchar
  createdAt timestamp
  updatedAt timestamp
```

---Answers---

```
  questionId int -> foreign ref to questions.id
  option int -> foreign ref to options.id
  value varchar -> free text in case a question didn't have options
  options ? -> array of option ids? 
  userId int -> foreign ref to users.id
  createdAt timestamp
  updatedAt timestamp
```

Now, I'm not sure how best to store the options in the answers table in case of a multiselect. Do I save an array of option ids? but that would render me unable to even have a foreign key ref to the options table and might make querying difficult since I need to be able to query the question-answer pairs for all questions by an individual user, this array wouldn't help me populate the options he chose. Please help me figure out the best way to store this.

Comment: I don't quite understand everything but one thing I'll say is `options` shouldn't reference `questions`. An option exists without any questions, so it should be "top level". A question has options, so the `questions` table should have a FK reference to `options`.

Comment: @404 An option is always for a particular question and won't be an option to any other question. Say if a,b,c,d are options for question 1, they're just for question 1 and to nothing else. If I make option a foreign key on the questions table, I'm not quite sure how I'd structure it if a question has multiple options. This was my thought with this approach. Not sure if I've understood this wrong. This is the first time I'm doing something like this

Comment: Ok I thought options was stuff like "single answer", "multiple answers", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My model would probably look something like this...Rich

```
--user table
user_id (primary key)
first_name 
last_name 
email 
create_date_time
update_date_time 

--survey master table, so you can reuse the model for additional surveys
survey_id (primary key)
survey_name
survey_description
create_date_time
update_date_time 

--question table
question_id (primary key)
survey_id (foreign key)
question_text
description
question_type
create_date_time
update_date_time 

--question answers table
answer_id (primary key)
question_id (foreign key)
answer_type
answer_text
answer_image
create_date_time
update_date_time 

--user answers table
user_id (primary key and foreign key)
question_id (primary key and foreign key)
answer_id (primary key if >1 answer allowed, and foreign key)
user_answer_text 
create_date_time
update_date_time
```

Comment: So does this mean that a combination of (userId, questionId, answerId) would act as the primary key in the answers table? So if a user selects 2 answers for a single question, do I set the same id key for both, something like this?    
`id  userId   questionId   answerId . 
1 1      1                  1 . 
1 1      1                  3 .` 
How do I query this table now if I want a list of answers by user and question, something like {  question: 'foo', answers: [answerOne, answerTwo] and also populate the answers with the option data like I cud've done if it were a single option selected

Comment: 1. yes, the combination is the primary key
2. if the user chooses 2 answers (e.g. What are your favorite colors and why?), you have 2 answers "1 1 1 'I love GREEN'"   "1 1 3 'I like RED too" kind of thing
3. to query the user answer, if you know the user_id, question_id, and answer_id it should be fairly easy, a simple SELECT * FROM user_answers WHERE user_id = 1 AND question_id = 1; kind of thing.  p.s. Belayer's model looks great too, both should be a good start for you.

Comment: Thank you. I also have an updated requirement wherein a question can lead to different questions based on the answers the user chooses. Please let me know if something like this would suffice in addition to the aforementioned model

Table --question_relationships-- 

`id 
parentQuestionId 
childQuestionId
optionId`

the parent and child ids being a foreign key to questions and the optionId to options.
So a combination of `parentId, childId, optionId` of say `8, 10, 1` and `8, 11, 2` would take the user to either the 10th or the 11th question depending on option chosen (1 or 2)

Comment: @RichMurnane Why do we need an answer_type and a question_type? Because I thought that with just question_type would be enough

Answer (score 1):

First cut at the model. Refining would require knowing more of the intended use of application. Owning Up: I would consider this a refinement of @RichMurnane's model.

```
--user table
  user_id (primary key)
  first_name 
  last_name 
  other user detail columns

--survey master table, so you can reuse the model for additional surveys
  survey_id (primary key)
  survey_name
  survey_description

--question table
  question_id (primary key)
  question_text
  description
  question_type
  image_id

--survey question table
  survey_question_id (primary key) 
  survey_id (foreign key)
  question_id (foreign key


--answers table
  survey_question_id (primary key, foreign key)
  user_id (primary key, foreign key)
  answer_type
  answer_text
  image_id

--image table 
  image_id (primary key) 
  image_url              (url/ file path to if externally stored)
  image                  (.jpg, .png, ...)
```